# Проблемы с версткой сайдбара

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Верстаю макет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Главная проблема в том, что он должен быть адаптивный, и я не пойму, как сделать, что бы расстояние уменьшалось, если уменьшается высота окна браузера.
Может кто то помочь советом?

**Попытка №2:**

Ссылки и лого это один блок и он прижат к верху, контакты это еще один блок и он будет прижат к низу. Как для остальных блоков сделать: что бы они занимали все оставшиеся пространство, а их содержимое было по центру.

Comment: Адаптивность по высоте браузера? Это что-то новенькое. Хотя тут нужно уточнить: расстояние чего должно уменьшаться?

Comment: логотип страшный

Answer (score 0):

Тут можно поступить также как и с шириной - через медиа запросы, например:

```
@media(min-height:401px){
  div{
    color:red;
  }
}
@media(max-height:400px){
  div{
    color:blue;
  }
}
```

При высоте больше 400px цвет шрифта красный, при высоте меньше - синий.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1: Логотип и Футер на `position:fixed`. Остальное скролится. Что является в общем предпочтительным. Так как что вы сможете сделать на телефоне в положении горизотнальном? Клиент ничего не увидит.

Вариант 2: использовать vh для разметки высоты.

```
#logo{height:50vh}
#footer{height:100vh;}
#middle{height:calc(100vh - 150vh);}
```

И дальше уже таким же образом для детей #middle стили писать. Только как выше написал, это нерешит проблему с горизонтальным положением телефона.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно при изменении положения телефона

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">
```

Тут подробнее https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Managing_screen_orientation

Answer (score 0):

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.another {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 100px;
}

.footer {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -ms-flex-align: end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Лого + меню</div>
  <div class="another">
    <div class="some-block">
      <p>Остальное</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Контакты + копирайт</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/deadrime/pen/EWweYK/ - вот мой вариант через flexbox.
Подробнее о том, как его использовать можно почитать тут - http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/